# Is there any addin for VisualStudio debugging to see DataTable content in a nice way?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, datatable, add-in

Do you know if there is any add-in for Visual Studio, that shows the content of any DataTable in a nice way when I hover on the relevant variable in Debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Data Debugger Visualizer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/datadebuggervisualizer.aspx) fits your needs.

It doesn't matter even if it doesn't. With Visual Studio's Debugger Visualizer feature you can easily create your own addin to handle your specific needs.  You may want to start with the following article if you'd like to have a try:-)

*[DataTips, Visualizers and Viewers Make Debugging .NET Code a Breeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163974.aspx)*

Comment: It looks cool! But did you posibly have a chance to test it on Visual Studio 2008 as well?

Comment: You only need to replace the assembly reference to make it work for VS2008. Read the comments of the code project article will give you a clue.